# Cannot set time in calendar class java

Tags: java, calendar

Hi below is my code.

```
public class DateSample {

public static void main(String as[]){
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("Curr : "+ c.getTime());
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR, 23);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    System.out.println("aftr : "+c.getTime());
}
}
```

Output is :

Curr : Wed Feb 27 15:02:44 CET 2013

aftr : Wed Feb 27 11:59:59 CET 2013

The ouput what I want is Wed Feb 26 23:59:59 CET 2013. But why this confusion? Pleass help.

Comment: Confusion? I don't understand.. what is the problem you're having?

Comment: It outputs correctly when I try it. It could be related to your time zone or locale. On my machine it outputs in 24-hour format, so it could also be fixed by the `HOUR_OF_DAY` answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [**Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY)

> Field number for get and set indicating the hour of the day.
>   HOUR_OF_DAY is used for the 24-hour clock. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM
>   the HOUR_OF_DAY is 22.

```
 c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
```

Comment: I guess the question is wrong by saying he wants Wed Feb 26 11:59:59 CET 201